# How to modify the function below to fetch all the elements based on the selected category?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to modify the function below to fetch all the elements based on the selected category? I simply want to fetch and show information without having to click on a button/ submission. Please guide how this can be achieved? I am open to suggestions.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function getProdNames(){
        //How to alter this to fetch & display all the elements from col (product_name) based on the selected category.
            var product_name = $('#category').find(':selected').data('product_name');
            
            $('#prodNames').val(product_name);
    
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
```

Php:

```
<body>
      <form>
        <select id="category" name="category" onClick="getProdNames();>
                <option> <?php
                            // Attempt select query execution
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
                            if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                                        while($r = $result->fetch_array()){
                                           echo "<option    
                                                data-productName='$r[2]' 
                                                data-color='$r[3]'
                                                value='$r[1]'> $r[1] </option>";}
                                } } ?>
                </option>
        </select>
    
    //Display Product Names based on the selected category here in the form of multi select list
    
    <input name="prodNames" id="prodNames"  class="form-control"/>
```

Desired output:
If user selects toy. This should trigger the onClick function to show all the productNames associated with this cateogory. Hence, the following output based on this example:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: You asked the exact same question earlier. Please don't duplicate questions. You aren't really showing enough html here for a [mre]. We have no idea how the option values match up to any other elements. Get rid of the server code and set this up with just html if you are wanting to do this with javascript

Comment: I have provided enough html. There is not much too it. Both the fields and the respective function is provided above.

Comment: It says you want to fetch the elements by category? **What elements?** PHP and SQL is not html and provides no sample `<option>` with real values to work with to compare to whatever the elements are. No ... this is definitely not a [mre]

Comment: It is a functional code. Instead of just displaying the single element $r[2] in the textfield (prodName). I want to show all the elements of $r[2] that match the category selected in $r[1].

Comment: Yes I know that but it is completely useless that way for running javascript in the browser to do what you are asking. The browser only understands valid html. I'm just telling you what is needed for anyone here to help you. Where are these elements? And how do they compare to the values of the options? You don't have enough pieces of the puzzle here

Comment: @charlietfl ok, I will add a live example to the post in a few hrs. Have to run some errands, thanks.

Comment: can we simply use js to fetch the data and show it in real-time?

Comment: Yes that is doable